# Mastodon::Listener: 1 at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Role/EventEmitter.pm line 21

Tags: perl, bots

I have the following example code copied from https://metacpan.org/pod/Mastodon::Client but it isn't working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mastodon::Client;

my $client = Mastodon::Client->new(
    instance=>'mastodon.cloud',
    name=>'Perl watcher',
    client_id=>'<myid>',
    client_secret=>'<mysecret>',
    access_token=>'<mytoken>',
    coerce_entities=>1
) or die "Cannot connect";
my $listener = $client->stream( 'public' );
$listener->on( update => sub {
    my ($listener, $status) = @_;
    printf "%s said: %s\n",
        $status->account->display_name,
        $status->content;
});
$listener->start;
```

It gives me the following error:

> Mastodon::Listener: 1 at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Role/EventEmitter.pm line 21.

This happen in the `$listener->start;` line exactly but I don't know why.

```
-- Emit error in Mastodon::Listener (0)
Mastodon::Listener: 1 at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Role/EventEmitter.pm line 21.
```

^ ROLE_EVENTEMITTER_DEBUG=1 v perl -d:Confess mastodon.pl

```
Mastodon::Listener: 1 at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Role/EventEmitter.pm line 21.
    Role::EventEmitter::emit(Mastodon::Listener=HASH(0x55d97ff65e90), "error", 1, "Can't locate IO/Async/SSL.pm in \@INC (you may need to install"..., ARRAY(0x55d980399a10)) called at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Listener.pm line 172
    Mastodon::Listener::__ANON__[/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Listener.pm:173](CODE(0x55d97fdca288), Mastodon::Listener=HASH(0x55d97ff65e90), "error", 1, "Can't locate IO/Async/SSL.pm in \@INC (you may need to install"..., ARRAY(0x55d980399a10)) called at (eval 400)[/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Class/Method/Modifiers.pm:89] line 1
    Mastodon::Listener::__ANON__[(eval 400)[/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Class/Method/Modifiers.pm:89]:1](Mastodon::Listener=HASH(0x55d97ff65e90), "error", 1, "Can't locate IO/Async/SSL.pm in \@INC (you may need to install"..., ARRAY(0x55d980399a10)) called at (eval 402)[/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Class/Method/Modifiers.pm:148] line 2
    Mastodon::Listener::emit(Mastodon::Listener=HASH(0x55d97ff65e90), "error", 1, "Can't locate IO/Async/SSL.pm in \@INC (you may need to install"..., ARRAY(0x55d980399a10)) called at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Listener.pm line 86
    Mastodon::Listener::__ANON__[/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Listener.pm:86](undef, undef, ARRAY(0x55d980399ae8)) called at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Listener.pm line 94
    Mastodon::Listener::__ANON__[/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Listener.pm:94](undef) called at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Async/HTTP.pm line 905
    Net::Async::HTTP::__ANON__[/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Async/HTTP.pm:906]("Can't locate IO/Async/SSL.pm in \@INC (you may need to install"...) called at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Future.pm line 1008
    Future::on_fail(Future=HASH(0x55d98037b678), CODE(0x55d98037af88)) called at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Async/HTTP.pm line 906
    Net::Async::HTTP::do_request(Net::Async::HTTP=HASH(0x55d97ff65ef0), "uri", "https://mastodon.cloud/api/v1/streaming/public", "headers", HASH(0x55d980399a70), "on_error", CODE(0x55d980399ab8), "on_header", ...) called at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Listener.pm line 146
    Mastodon::Listener::start(Mastodon::Listener=HASH(0x55d97ff65e90)) called at mastodon.pl line 21
```

If I change `$_[0]` to `$_[1]` in the error file `/home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Role/EventEmitter.pm` line 21 and installed the missing library IO::Async::SSL, I get:

```
-- Emit error in Mastodon::Listener (0)
Mastodon::Listener: Error decoding JSON payload: Reference bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ) did not pass type constraint "Bool" (in $args->{"locked"}) at /home/sergio/perl5/lib/perl5/Mastodon/Types.pm line 83
    Reference bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ) did not pass type constraint "Bool" (in $args->{"locked"})
    "Bool" is defined as: (Type::Tiny::XS::Bool($_))
```

Comment: What output do you get if you run your script under `ROLE_EVENTEMITTER_DEBUG=1`?

Comment: Also, what do you get from `perl -d:Confess script.pl`?

Comment: @melpomene I think I figured out the error thank for your help

Comment: Now I get other error...

Comment: Ah. It's dumb that `Role::EventEmitter` hides error details by default. You might want to report a feature request that [this line](https://metacpan.org/source/DBOOK/Role-EventEmitter-0.003/lib/Role/EventEmitter.pm#L21) be changed to print `@_` instead of just `$_[0]`.

Comment: @melpomene If I do so the error is less descriptive yet, it prints nothing.

Comment: Upgraded question @melpomene

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly did you change where?

Comment: @melpomene The file you said me to report I put $_[1] exactly on this line instead of $@ as you suggested.

Comment: I never said anything about `$_[1]` or `$@`. WTF?

Comment: >Ah. It's dumb that Role::EventEmitter hides error details by default. You might want to report a feature request that this line be changed to print @_ instead of just $_[0].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194429/discussion-between-melpomene-and-sergiotarxz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate that Role::EventEmitter hides the details of that error by default. At least `perl -d:Confess` shows useful information in the stack trace.

Otherwise you could have recovered the error message by registering an `error` handler:

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
$listener->on( error => sub {
    my ($is_fatal, $message, $details) = @_;
    die "error ($is_fatal): $message\n" . Dumper($details);
});
```

The actual error message,

```
Can't locate IO/Async/SSL.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ...)
```

just means you need to install the [IO::Async::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::SSL) module.

---

The `... did not pass type constraint "Bool" (in $args->{"locked"}) ...` error looks like [issue #10 in Mastodon::Client](https://gitlab.com/jjatria/Mastodon-Client/issues/10). There is a [patch](https://gitlab.com/jjatria/Mastodon-Client/commit/2f3fcdf1031d9ba524e6314dbb8b1e730f530f5d), but it hasn't made it into an official Mastodon::Client release yet.

A possible workaround might be to downgrade Type::Tiny to version 1.003002 or lower.

Comment: When I installed IO::Async::SSL I get another error saying JSON payload cannot be decoded. It is in the question, just to point it to readers.

Comment: It works fine upgrading Mastodon Client to the last version, thank you for the help and for correct typos in my question.

Comment: The error event is defined to be handled in a certain way: the first value (after the invocant) is the error message. This is necessary because Perl only works in string exceptions. I am not sure why Mastodon::Client put a boolean there instead of the message.